# how to do paging for TableViewer jface?

Tags: java, pagination, swt, tableviewer

I created application with `TableViewer` in eclipse.
The `TableViewer` is import from `org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TableViewer`

The table has a lot of data.

When I scroll on the table I want to see the next result of the table (Paging)

Do you know if there is something generic for this ?

Comment: What toolkit are you using for the table viewer (SWT perhaps)?

Comment: SWT org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TableViewer

Comment: I suggest you to try to use Eclipse Nebula Pagination (http://www.eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/pagination/pagination.php) It manages pagination with SWT Table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code that will do what (I think) you want:

```
private static int page = 0;
private static int pageSize = 10;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    final Table table = new Table(shell, SWT.NONE);
    table.addListener(SWT.MouseWheel, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event e)
        {
            if(e.count < 0)
                addItems(table, page++);
            else if(e.count > 0)
                addItems(table, page--);
        }
    });

    addItems(table, page);

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}

private static void addItems(Table table, int topIndex)
{
    table.removeAll();
    for(int i = 0; i < pageSize; i++)
    {
        TableItem item = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
        item.setText("Item: " + (i + (topIndex * pageSize)));
    }
}
```

It will listen for `MouseWheel` events on the `Table` and update the content accordingly.

---

Same holds for `TableViewer`s instead of `Table`s, just replace the `Listener` with this:

```
table.addListener(SWT.MouseWheel, new Listener()
{
    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event e)
    {
        if(e.count < 0)
            viewer.setInput(ModelProvider.INSTANCE.getItems(page++));
        else if(e.count > 0)
            viewer.setInput(ModelProvider.INSTANCE.getItems(page--));
    }
});
```

Comment: I want that the scroll will work when I do scrolling and not with buttons

Comment: @user1365697 That's not paging then. So you simply want the table to scroll? Where are you having problems accomplishing this?

Comment: First I can see only 20 results when I will do scroll on the table I want to see the next 20 results according to the scrolling

Comment: @user1365697 That doesn't answer any of the two questions I asked.

Comment: I want to scroll the table.The table can show only 10 results.When I will do scroll I need to show the next result.Does it mean to implement paging ? I didn't understand what you meant